# TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator

Tags: python, json

I am having trouble with some variable types in my code. The error that I get now is:

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
```

The code line in question is the following:

```
valor_anual[data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['geodsg']][year_code] = statistics.mean(valor_mensal_aux)
```

Here is a snippet of my code to give you guys context:

```
valor_anual = [0][0]

for city_code in city_codes:

    for year_code in year_codes:
        valor_mensal_aux = []
        for month_code in month_codes:

            url_imob = Request(
                "https://www.ine.pt/ine/json_indicador/pindica.jsp?op=2&varcd=0010042&Dim1=S3A" + year_code + \
                month_code + "&Dim2=" + city_code + "&Dim3=T&lang=PT", headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})
            json_date = year_code + month_code
            response = urlopen(url_imob)
            data = json.loads(response.read())
            valor_mensal_aux.append(data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['valor'])

        valor_anual[data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['geodsg']][year_code] = statistics.mean(valor_mensal_aux)

        python_imob = Imob(year_code, valor_anual[city_code][year_code], data['DataUltimoAtualizacao'],
                           data['Dados'][json_date]['geodsg'])
        session.add(python_imob)  
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        imobs = session.query(Imob).all()
```

The JSON that I'm getting data from has the following structure:

```json
[ {
  "IndicadorCod" : "0010042",
  "IndicadorDsg" : "Valor mediano de avaliação bancária (€/ m²) por Localização geográfica (Município - 2013) e Tipo de construção; Mensal - INE, Inquérito à avaliação bancária na habitação",
  "MetaInfUrl" : "https://www.ine.pt/bddXplorer/htdocs/minfo.jsp?var_cd=0010042&lingua=PT",
  "DataExtracao" : "2020-06-29T15:55:51.640+01:00",
  "DataUltimoAtualizacao" : "2020-06-29",
  "UltimoPref" : "Maio de 2020",
  "Dados" : {
    "202005" : [ {
      "geocod" : "1701106",
      "geodsg" : "Lisboa",
      "dim_3" : "T",
      "dim_3_t" : "Total",
      "valor" : "3084"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer below help you?

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to fix this?

Comment: sorry man, i was on vacation and got back today. Actually, i having some type of errors like this one and i might need more help to get my code working, i think i am making a new post..

Answer (score 1):

How about typecasting

```
valor_anual[int(data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['geodsg'])][int(year_code)]
```

Comment: i made the changes that u pointed and i got the error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Viana do Castelo'

Comment: it might be because of "geodsg" is the name of the cities(like Viana do Castelo) and it cant be transformed in an integer..

Comment: @TiagoMendes what data structure is valor_anual?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give an exact solution without the full source code, however I suspect your issue is that you are attempting to take the mean of valor_mensal_aux which contains string elements. Try converting "valor" to an integer before appending it to the list:

```
valor_mensal_aux.append(int(data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['valor']))
```